# Google graph not accepting PHP Variables

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I am using Google Charts to create a line graph. However in the JavaScript part I try passing my PHP variables into the array however i get an error message which reads:

Not enough columns given to draw the requested chart.

My Code:

```
<!-- Google Charts -->
<div id="chart_line_graph" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<?
    $titleArray = array(
                        'Week'
                        );
        $count = 0;
        //Get all headers
        $query = 'SELECT `keyword` FROM `'.$tableName.'` ORDER BY `keyword`';
        $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){
            if($count < 5) //Get first 5 keywords
                $titleArray[] = $row['keyword'];
            $count++;
        }

        $data = array();
        $data[] = json_encode($titleArray);

        foreach($columns as $column){
            $weekData = array();
            $weekData[] = "'".$column."'";
            $query = 'SELECT `'.$column.'`  FROM `'.$tableName.'` ORDER BY `keyword`';
            $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            $count = 0;
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){
                if($count < 5)
                    $weekData[] = (Integer)$row[$column];
                $count++;
            }
            $data[] = json_encode($weekData);
        }

?> 

<script>
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    <?php
        foreach($data as $weekData){
            echo $weekData.',';
        }
      ?>    

    ],false);

    var options = {
      title: '<?echo ucwords($_SESSION['clientName']);?> Keywords',
      curveType: 'function',
      legend: { position: 'right' }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_line_graph'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
    </script>
```

Every time I run it I get the same error message. I've tried outputting the results and copied and pasted it into the JavaScript directly and the graph got created.

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Edit:

The data :

```
["Week","aker aberdeen","alma tavern","ancillary items","baby change sign","baby change units"],
["10_12_2015",36,11,37,30,48],
["17_12_2015",36,10,35,27,43],
["24_12_2015",26,11,35,26,44],
["31_12_2015",29,11,32,23,42],
```

Comment: will you show us what the data looks like, that you feed to `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable`

Comment: I can't comment on the PHP side because I'm not strong in that area, but make sure that data is what actually appears in the code that the browser is receiving. Your Array structure looks ok. The error you're getting suggests that it is not getting your array, though. Or the array is malformed (like there's some quotes around it or something).

Comment: When I viewed the source it was missing the numbers on the arrays, I'm not sure why its not picking it up

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For some reason the mysqli wasn't working correctly. I change it from the procedural way to the object oriented way and it all worked. I don't know why it did I just know it worked.